Understanding the proof of Upcrossing inequality
I'm struggling with the proof of upcrossing inequality in the context of stochastic process
Here is the proof from the book Probability: Theory and Examples by Rick Durrett
$Proof. $ Let $Y_m=a+(X_m-a)^+$. By theorem 4.2.7, $Y_m$ is a submartingale. Clearly, it upcrosses [a,b] the same number of times that $X_m$ does, and we have $(b-a)U_n\le (H\cdot Y)_n$, since each upcrossing results in a profit $\ge (b-a)$ and a final incomplete upcrossing (if there is one) makes a nonnegative contribution to the right-hand side. It is for this reason we had to replace $X_m$ by $Y_m$.
Let $K_m=1-H_m$. Clearly, $Y_n-Y_0=(H\cdot Y)_n+(K\cdot Y)_n$, and it follows from Theorem 4.2.8 that $E(K\cdot Y)_n\ge E(K\cdot Y)_0=0$ so $E(H\cdot Y)\le E(Y_n-Y_0)$, proving the desired inequality. $\Box$
I don't understand why the inequality $$(b-a)U_n\le (H\cdot Y)_n$$ holds, where $U_n=\sup \{k:N_{2k}\le n\}$ is the number of upcrossings completed by time n and $H_n$ is the predictable sequence, $(H\cdot Y)_n=\sum_{m=1}^{n}H_m(Y_m-Y_{m-1})$

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

@JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for your advice, edited.
